# Squareup iFrame not allowed

Tags: tomcat, iframe, square-connect

I'm new to Square and trying to get their simple SqPaymentForm working under Tomcat / Eclipse / Firefox.  I get the below load denied error when the form comes up.  The iFrames seem to work as I can enter data in them and post it.  However, I am receiving 2 errors.

Every time the form loads I get the following error.  I have tried including the security filter settings in the default eclipse tomcat web.xml and also in the web app's web.xml.  I've even tried turning off anti click jacking but that didn't work either.

Any suggestions would be appreciated...

Load denied by X-Frame-Options: https://connect.squareup.com/v2/logo.html?s=MY-ID does not permit cross-origin framing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

    <filter>
        <filter-name>httpHeaderSecurity</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter</filter-class>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>antiClickJackingEnabled</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>antiClickJackingOption</param-name>
            <param-value>SAMEORIGIN</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>antiClickJackingUri</param-name>
            <param-value>https://connect.squareup.com</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

</web-app>
```

The 2nd error I get is:

```
TypeError: event is undefined
   requestCardNonce()
   TestSquare1.jsp:142
   onclick()
```

This error is generated from the payment form "event.preventDefault()":

```
// This function is called when a buyer clicks the Submit button on the webpage to charge their card.
function requestCardNonce(event)
{
    // This prevents the Submit button from submitting its associated form.
    // Instead, clicking the Submit button should tell the SqPaymentForm to generate
    // a card nonce, which the next line does.
    event.preventDefault();

    paymentForm.requestCardNonce();
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your second error first: 
You probably have a mistake in your code when you call `requestCardNonce(event)` such that it only says `requestCardNonce()` when you submit the form, leaving the `event` variable undefined inside the function.

Your first error is a little trickier. It sounds like the iframe loads, but there is also an error. If you can load the iframe and get it to work, that sounds like a win to me. Could you share some more of the code that has the iframe?

Comment: Sure, I can share code but I'm not sure how to upload a file here.  I have a simple HTML web page.  In the mean time, I took the code directly from Square's developer site.  The event parameter is there by default.  Here's the link: 

https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/adding-payment-form/?q=embed%20payment%20form

Comment: Yeah, looks like there is a bug with that file. You shouldn't have any problem processing payments however.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Is the event the bug?  I can't put transactions through without a nonce and that has to come from a SqPaymentForm which I can't get working due to the X-Frame thing.  Even if I comment out requestCardNonce(event)

Comment: The x-frame thing shouldn't be an issue. I am pretty sure you have a javascript error: if you copied the sample code, replace this line `<input type="submit" onclick="requestCardNonce()">` with `<input type="submit" onclick="requestCardNonce(event)">`

Comment: Fantastic!  That worked.  I get the nonce now.  Still have the X-Frame error which I don't understand as I have it turned off in the app's web.xml.  For now I can move forward until that's figured out.  Thanks very much.

Comment: Super, if you have any more questions, tag them `square-connect`